# .htaccess - Redirect

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess

What I want is to redirect by .htaccess

> http://example.com/omgitsaname

I want really to redirect, or better, to stay the same but to get the information from

> http://example.com/product?id=omgitsaname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use these types of URL's in your browser

```
http://example.com/omgitsaname
```

You can do it this way and make sure the that the URI is not a real directory or a file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /product?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I can't reply that, it's a 500 internal error, can you explain better?

Comment: There isn't much to explain. It does as I mentioned. You need to check your apache error_log to see why it's giving you an 500 error. Logs are for troubleshooting so we aren't guessing as to what's wrong. It will tell you why it's giving the 500 when you use this rule and then we can proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use `Rewrite Rules` via `.htaccess`, in `Apache`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/?$ do/something/here [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$  product?id=$1  [NC,L]
```

Make sure the `mod_rewrite` module (or equivalent) is enabled.
Also add the following rule: `AllowOverride all` (or equivalent) to allow `.htaccess` to work.

**Note**: Modify the regular expression as per your needs.
**Edit**: Thanks to @4sha to fix the redirect loop.

Comment: This will cause a loop because `^([a-z]+)/?$` matces `product`

Comment: No, it will not because the URL in the case of `product` is different. It does not end there. `.htaccess` does not do partial matches. It matches the whole string including the query string.

Comment: The regex does not match the query string, only `%{THE_REQUEST}` or `%{QUERY_STRING}` can match query string

Comment: @4sha Thank you for fixing that! I verified that. Added a higher priority rule as the easiest approach.

Comment: I tested and it actually doesn't cause a rewrite loop, it does if the rule's target is `/product?id=$1`, but the regex in a 1`RewriteRule1` will *not* match query strings